# create a random integer unique in a given array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id='passarr'>1572 4528 3564 8921 4521</div>
```

I need to create **a new** random integer (4 digits), unique regarding the above content.

**js**

```
var content = $('#passarr').text();
var passarr = content.split(' ');
var pass = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
var i = 0;
while (i == 0) {
    if (jQuery.inArray(pass, passarr) > -1) {
        var pass = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

seems it works, but not sure this is the right and shortest way.
any suggestion?

Comment: Is `#passarr` the result?

Comment: It looks like the boolean expression in your `if` statement should actually be the boolean expression in the `while` statement. You don't need `i`.

Comment: @zer00ne, no, result is `pass`

Comment: I think what @4castle meant was `while (jQuery.inArray(pass, passarr) === -1)) { ... }`

Comment: Part of the issue is you have `var pass` twice I assume.  take the `var` off the inner pass.

Comment: @RobM. Yeah, I misread their code and thought they had written the opposite of what I thought, which means they need `> -1` in the `while` loop if they're trying to generate new numbers.

Comment: This works by luck. In (5/9000)**2 cases, it wont work... ;0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is the way to go. However, you can eliminate a few smaller mistakes ( an unneccessary i and non working code in < 0.00001%) :

```
var content = $('#passarr').text();
var passarr = content.split(' ');
do {
  var pass = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
} while (jQuery.inArray(pass, passarr) > -1);

console.log(pass);
```

Comment: This is exactly the algorithm they need. My only suggestion is to move the declaration of `var pass` to be outside of the loop, so that someone who isn't aware of hoisting won't be confused by the scope of `pass`.

Comment: @4castle thats actually a point for not changing it. Theyll wonder that this works, and will be more clever afterwards ;)

Comment: excellent, later I saw that my code in fact doesn't work. This works. thanks a  lot.